# Creating a three dimensional fullerene molecule

Tags: plotting, graphics, chemistry

How do I modify the following program to create a nice coloured molecular plot of C60 or fullerene as shown in the attached figure

[image]

This figure was retrieved from http://asserttrue.blogspot.com.au/2013/03/olive-oil-fullerene-and-lifespan.html#

```
pos = {{4.20790955, 1.12423579, 5.0724025}, {5.92255243, 0.30577656, 
    3.09053347}, {2.53625794, -0.58931105, 6.15449739}, 
       {5.89150423, -2.19125067,  2.27598598}, {6.07911622, -2.76287388, -0.40300296}, {6.14208189, 2.34350589, 1.26288498}, 
       {6.32168145, 1.79658139, -1.30022597}, {6.28972619, -0.81331917, -2.15152863}, {-0.85451519, 2.59699373, 6.10424958}, 
       {0.89249869, 4.38777367, 4.97351314}, {-0.0510226, 0.16353689, 
    6.68186323}, {3.36781297, 3.66786366, 4.46912637}, 
       {4.56285678, 4.42127851, 2.11483015}, {-1*0.4993034, 
    5.8930727, 3.14654495}, {0.64416979, 6.61402206, 0.89416165}, 
       {3.23137475, 5.86189222, 
    0.36707927}, {-4.0468482, -1.59965305, 5.07597408}, {-4.88658574, 
    0.94354019, 4.47250898}, 
       {-1.6827443, -1.98120762, 6.15625484}, {-3.32578546, 
    2.99557474, 4.97542176}, {-3.10623709, 5.03232141, 3.14743312}, 
       {-6.29775752, 0.83554235, 2.119271}, {-6.08784676, 2.78439786, 
    0.37044299}, {-4.45682426, 4.92933134, 0.89618365}, 
       {-0.95746747, -5.66581425, 
    3.40868774}, {-3.4282275, -5.26727104, 
    2.27991661}, {-0.10387824, -4.05947157, 5.30402621}, 
       {-4.93898784, -3.27912812, 
    3.09521999}, {-6.32980727, -1.77424483, 
    1.26783606}, {-3.2399919, -5.83991471, -0.39909123}, 
       {-4.57094481, -4.40022696, -2.14742792}, {-6.15020772, 
-2.32243545, -1.29533158}, {4.14416909, -3.98220068, 3.40634448}, 
       {3.25204835, -5.66116553, 
    1.42568487}, {2.50352789, -3.19913602, 
    5.30279789}, {0.75764784, -6.48459473, 1.4268754}, 
       {-0.65282474, -6.59204455, -0.92630589}, {4.44820711, \
-4.90778847, -0.92840348}, {3.0986026, -5.01057066, -3.17986082}, 
       {0.4916878, -5.87162431, -3.17872698}, {-4.21537397, \
-1.1041291, -5.10475461}, {-3.37499392, -3.64732234, -4.50151628}, 
       {-0.8993395, -4.36660874, -5.00582745}, {-2.5441003, 
    0.61009804, -6.18628259}, {-4.15359883, 4.00310105, -3.4385832}, 
       {-5.90029145, 
    2.21167861, -2.30835699}, {-5.93067825, -0.2855187, -3.12307455}, \
{-2.51263637, 3.22020647, -5.33473426}, 
       {0.94767869, 5.68830199, -3.44022726}, {-0.76728544, 
    6.50657224, -1.4586417}, {-3.26164816, 5.6827084, -1.45786691}, 
       {0.09442961, 4.08156247, -5.33543346}, {4.03843892, 
    1.62287778, -5.10734353}, {4.93027621, 3.30214499, -3.126854}, 
       {3.41902454, 5.29011783, -2.3116829}, {1.67416495, 
    2.00384654, -6.18737863}, {0.847561, -2.57503512, -6.13588359}, 
       {3.3185856, -2.97318149, -5.00728254}, {4.87893235, \
-0.92061781, -4.50446425}, {0.0434637, -0.14161607, -6.7131004}}; 
atype = {"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
   "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
       "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
   "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
   "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"}; 
dataC = AssociationThread[Range[Length[atype]], 
   Transpose[{atype, pos}]]; 
writeXYZ[file_String, data_] := 
 Module[{str = OpenWrite[file, FormatType -> OutputForm], 
   len = Length[data]}, 
     Scan[
   WriteLine[str, #1] & , {ToString[len], 
    "            Coordinates (Angstroms)"}]; 
      Scan[Write[str, "    ", data[#1][[1]], 
     PaddedForm[data[#1][[2, 1]], {14, 6}], 
     PaddedForm[data[#1][[2, 2]], {10, 6}], 
            PaddedForm[data[#1][[2, 3]], {10, 6}]] & , Range[len]]; 
  Close[str]]
writeXYZ["testC.xyz", dataC]; 
Import["testC.xyz", "XYZ"]
```

Comment: There is a nice built-in function `ChemicalData["FullereneC60", "MoleculePlot"]`

Comment: Not to mention: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/MolecularGraphTheoryAppliedToFullerenes/

Comment: @ybeltukov Yes that built-in function is gd, but really need differentiation in bonds/atoms via colours

Comment: The output from the built-in MoleculePlot is just a Graphics3D expression with spheres for the atoms and cylinders for the bonds. So use something like `% /. {c_Cylinder :> Style[c, Red], s_Sphere :> Style[s, Blue]}`

Comment: As written, your coordinates are actually in Bohr, so you need to convert to angstroms.  This uses your coordinates, but doesn't get differently colored bonds:  `ImportString[
  ExportString[Transpose[Join[{atype}, Transpose@(0.529177 pos)]], 
   "Table"], "XYZ"] /. {Cylinder[a__] :> {Yellow, Cylinder[a]}, 
  Sphere[a__] :> {Blue, Sphere[a]}}`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One can colorize bonds by finding 5-cycles in the bounding graph

```
pts = QuantityMagnitude@ChemicalData["FullereneC60", "AtomPositions"];
graph = UndirectedGraph@Graph@ChemicalData["FullereneC60", "EdgeRules"];
ring5 = List @@@ Flatten@FindCycle[graph, {5}, 12];
remain = Complement[List @@@ EdgeList[graph], ring5, ring5[[All, {2, 1}]]];

Graphics3D@GraphicsComplex[pts, {Blue, Ball[Range@60, 30], Red, Tube[ring5, 10], Yellow, 
   Tube[remain, 10]}]
```

[image]

For version 9 and earlier you should delete `QuantityMagnitude@`.

---

After tuning the lightning

```
Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[pts, {Specularity[White, 20], Lighter@Blue, Ball[Range@60, 30], 
  Red, Tube[ring5, 10], Yellow, Tube[remain, 10]}], Boxed -> False, 
 Background -> Black, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", GrayLevel[0.2]}, {"Directional", 
    GrayLevel[0.8], {{0, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, -1.5}}}}]
```

[image]

Comment: How to add lighting effects...see original pic

Comment: @thils See my update :)

Comment: NB in v9 `FindCycle[]` is still a Combinatorica function